# SOIC to DIP Adapter - 16-Pin

Tags: surface-mount, adapter, dip

I bought a IC (AD5933), its mounting Style is SMD/SMT.
I would like to do a test with it in the protoboard, however I am confused about the type of adapter.
I want to use an adapter that does not need soldering, [like this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/SO16-SOP16-to-DIP16-Wide-150mil-Programmer-adapter-Socket-/281798530395?hash=item419c80555b:g:3tIAAOSwc0FUqliN).
[image]

But, I'm not sure exactly the right size for my case (150mil, 300mil, ...).
**I do not understand if those values (150mil, 300mil) are for height or width.**
Can someone help me?

*Here are the specifications according to website Mouser:*

Product Category:           Data Acquisition ADCs/DACs - Specialized

Manufacturer:               Analog Devices Inc. RoHS: RoHS Compliant Details

Product:                    DDS Direct Digital Synthesis ICs

Type:                       DDS Impedance Converter Resolution: 12 bit

Number of Channels:         1 Channel

Operating Supply Voltage:   2.7 V to 5.5 V

Mounting Style:             SMD/SMT Package / Case: SSOP-16 Packaging: Tube

Brand:                      Analog Devices

Development Kit:            EVAL-AD5933EBZ

Height:                     1.75 mm Length: 6.2 mm

Number of Converters:       1 Converter Sampling Rate: 1 MS/s

Series:                     AD5933

Factory Pack Quantity:      77

Supply Voltage - Max:       5.5 V

Supply Voltage - Min:       2.7 V

Width:                      5.3 mm

Unit Weight:                130 mg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of different types of SMD part, with many widths (distance between the two rows of pins), many pitches (spacing of adjacent pins), number of pins, etc.

SOIC is a fairly common one. These are usually 0.05" pitch (1.27mm), and come in wither 0.15" or 0.3" widths typically.

Your part however is neither, it is a SSOP-16 package which will not work with that adapter. SSOP packages are a lot more varied. In your case you have a 0.65mm pitch device with a body width of about 5.3mm and a row pitch of 7.8mm.

ZIF to DIP adapters for such parts are available, such as the [WELLS CTI 656C1202215-001](http://www.newark.com/wells-cti/656c1202215-001/socket-ic-ssop-zif/dp/99K0197) (you will likely find cheaper ones on eBay or the like). The key thing before buying one is to verify the pin-to-pin pitch and widths match the adapter by cross-referencing the part datasheet with the adapter specifics.

Comment: Wells CTI seems to have all but disappeared as of Oct 2020. I had some luck finding suppliers at Alibaba through [this internet search.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=IC+socket+SO16&t=ffnt&iax=images&ia=images) The good news is that the prices are a small fraction of the Wells CTI parts - but I don't know about the quality yet... ask me in a month.

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5933.pdf) for this device includes the device package measurements at the end of the document. They show this to be a wide SSOP package and give the width as 5.3mm for the body and 7.8mm for the whole including the pins. 300mil is about 7.6mm so it looks like you need a wide version of your adapter.

However, you also need to check the pin pitch as this can vary. The datasheet says the 0.65mm but your adapter is for a wider pitch type at 1.27mm. So this will not fit your chip. The cheap solderable SMT to DIP adapter PCBs typically have two pitches supported, one on each side as this is quite common. (eg: [this example](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10Pcs-SOP16-SSOP16-TSSOP16-SMD-to-DIP-Adapter-IC-Converter-Adapter-DIP16-IC-PCB/272502570790?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D20131003132420%26meid%3D9cd3cb6b5ae14cec84ba3351af4016b6%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D5%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D181116683878) where they show the pin pitch on the silk screen).